# ios app getting device authentic error for chromecast

Tags: ios, chromecast, ajp

Not able to connect ChromeCast device.

When trying to reconnect chromecast device, getting the following errors:

- [GCKDeviceAuthChannel timerDidFire:] authentication timed out
- [GCKCastDeviceConnector deviceAuthChannel:didFailToAuthenticateWithError:] Not an authentic device, disconnecting.

Error Domain=com.google.GCKError Code=3 "Device authentication failure" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Device authentication failure}

I captured packet and noticed that iphone received ajp13 error packet.

Please let me know how I can connect to Chromecast.
Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the phones date and time setting. It could be the cause of the certificate problem in the phone and Chromecast. You may wan to visit [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831694/ios-app-getting-a-device-authentication-error-when-scanning-for-chromecast-dev) for possible answers. Also, try to check it with other iOS devices. If the problem still exist.

For further information and support for your issue, you can visit the [Chromecast support here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/support).